# Jajascript do while

Tags: javascript

Del siguiente calculador de medias, ¿cómo puedo hacer para que cuando introduzca el "0", no calcule la media de ese número? Muestra "la media de 0 es 0", pero no quiero que me aparezca eso.

```js
do{
    
    var numero=prompt("Introduce un numero")*1;
    var num=(parseInt(numero));
    var media=num/2;
    alert("La media de " +numero+ " es " +media);
    
    }while(numero!=0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Hacer un condicional en el interior de bucle seria una sencilla solución.

```
do{

    var numero=prompt("Introduce un numero");

    if(numero == 0){
       alert("No puede ser 0");
    }else{

       var num=(parseInt(numero));
       var media=num/2;
       alert("La media de " +numero+ " es " +media);

    }

}while(numero!=0);
```

Si mantienes la condición del `while();` ten en cuenta que el programa avisará de que *"no puede ser 0"* y no continuará la ejecución del bucle. Si quieres que continue debes cambiar la condición del `while();`